# Replace string in filename in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash

So I have this function

```
ren_barrow(){
    for file in *.clu
    do
        mv -f $file ${file//RELEASE/"$1"}
    done
}
```

but when I run this, as you can see everyfile that ends in .clu will be renamed.

I want to put an if statement around the `mv` that says if the filename contains RELEASE in it then carry on. If I do not have this if statement I get errors saying

`Cannot rename: $file and $file is the same file.`

```
ren_barrow(){
    for file in *.clu
    do
        # if $file grep "RELEASE"; then
            mv -f $file ${file//RELEASE/"$1"}
        # fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your `mv` command like this:

```
[[ "$file" != *"RELEASE"* ]] && mv -f "$file" "${file//RELEASE/$1}"
```

Comment: Thank you, would you mind explaining how this statement works?

Comment: This condition `[[ "$file" != *"RELEASE"* ]]` is using a glob pattern to determine whether `$filename` doesn't already contain text `RELEASE` in it.

Comment: Also see guide on [BASH Globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why not change your `for` loop so that you don't have to iterate over all the files?

```
for file in *RELEASE*.clu
do
    mv -f "$file" "${file//RELEASE/$1}"
done
```

Even better, use the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command if you have it:

```
rename RELEASE "" *RELEASE*.clu
```